# "На двадцать три дюймовом колесе" (цитата) как правильно пишется?

Tags: орфография, числительные

Слова из припева песни:

[На двадцать три дюймовом колесе.](https://xn--b1agamykmd.xn--p1ai/song/poligraf_sharikoff_seryoga/gelik_vani)

Comment: А сами-то как думаете? Это вопрос уровня домашнего задания, а мы их обычно не выполняем.

Comment: "двадцатитрехдюймовом" Слитно причем. А что там в песне - это в "нарочно не придумаешь".

Answer (score 4):

Двадцатитрехдюймовом. Или 23-дюймовом.

Comment: Верно. Вот только составные числительные слитно не пишутся, так что поправьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Дорогой друг, поправьте свои знания в правописании числительных. Можете заодно освежить в памяти Маяковского ("иду красивый, двадцатидвухлетний") или повторить курс истории СССР ("двадцатипятитысячники").

Comment: @БотБотович А как правильно? Покажите свой вариант.

Comment: @Niemand Я исправила вопрос. А общее впечатление от беседы: понаехали тут.